# How to click button using selenium webdriver java, whose xpath is not constant

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver in Java. I am using webdriver with Firefox Quantum (59.0, x64). The problem I am facing is that the website i am writing code for testing dose not have constant xpath. On every visit the button id changes. Even the classname(launchbutton) is same for all 4 Launch Buttons. So while writing code it initially worked & opened the first link, but for second link it again opened the first link as the classname is same for all 4 buttons. Please help me out to code to open other links too by pressing other launch button.

i used this(below) code but it worked partially. Please help me out as i want to launch using button of other subjects too. (Please refer screenshot)[checkout screenshot1 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq48W.jpg)
[checkout screenshot2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1TYI.jpg)

Also i am not able to switch between tabs. pls help.
thankyou

```
driver.findElement(By.className("launchbutton")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: While the Id may be changing as you said the class does not. When getting the elements by className you will end up with a node collection, which you will need to search through for the proper button. One thing you probably can bet on is the innerText of the button. You can grab the elements by className, then iterate over the collection checking each one's innerText to see if matches the button you want to click. I will provide an example answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Grab all elements which have the className "launchbutton"
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("launchbutton"));

//Iterate your list of matching elements and look at the innerText for the button you want
//When found, click it and break the for loop
foreach(WebElement ele in elements)
{
    if(ele.getAttribute("innerText") == "The button text you want")
    {
         ele.Click();
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click the Launch button as below and please change the code based on the mentioned comments

```
        //Specify the Expected Name in the below String
        String subjectName="";

        //Find the Table Element using any one of the Unique Locator
        WebElement table=driver.findElement(By.id(""));
        List<WebElement> rowElementList=table.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr"));

        //I have assumed Launch button column in 5th.So, Specified as td[4].
        //Please cross check the Launch button column and change the index accordingly
        for(WebElement element:rowElementList){
            if(element.findElement(By.xpath("./td")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(subjectName)){
                element.findElement(By.xpath("./td[4]/a")).click();
            }
        }
```